# How to use ng-repeat with indexes in html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have got a case in which is difiicult to explain so i put screen shots as follows

CASE:1-
   [image]

Initailly when i click on add-on-one-field,i get the heading div like below,

CASE:2-
  [image]

When i click on add-button,i get the fields displayed,like below

CASE:3-
  When i click on the button for headin only heading should come but the fields also comming of first one which is a bug.
   [image]

My html,

```
<div class="input-field col s12">
                   <fieldset  data-ng-repeat="addon in Addonchoice">
                        <div class="input-field col s8">
                            <input type="text" id="addonheader" ng-model="addon.heading" class="form-control" required>

                            <label for="heading">Heading<span class="error_red">*</span></label>

                            <xt-validation-inline for="addonheader"></xt-validation-inline>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-field col s4">
                            <button  type = "button" class="btn addfields" ng-click="addonsdata()">ADD</button>
                            <button  ng-click="removeAddons('default_status',$index)" class="btn btn-danger">Remove</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-field col s12">
                            <fieldset data-ng-repeat="addondata in Addondata">
                                <div class="input-field col s4">
                                    <input type="text" id="addonname" ng-model="addondata.name" class="form-control" required>

                                    <label for="name">Name<span class="error_red">*</span></label>

                                    <xt-validation-inline for="addonname"></xt-validation-inline>
                                </div>
                                <div class="input-field col s4">
                                    <input type="text" id="addonprice" ng-model="addondata.price" class="form-control" required>

                                    <label for="price">Price<span class="error_red">*</span></label>

                                    <xt-validation-inline for="addonprice"></xt-validation-inline>
                                </div>
                                <div class="input-field col s4">
                                     <button  type = "button" class="btn addfields" ng-click="addonsdata()">ADD</button>
                                    <button  type = "button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="()">Remove</button>
                                </div>
                            </fieldset>   
                        </div>
                   </fieldset>
                </div>
                <button type = "button" class="btn addfields" ng-click="addAddons()">Add Add-ons fields</button>
```

My js,

```
$scope.addAddons = function(){
        var newItemNo = $scope.Addonchoice.length+1;
        $scope.Addonchoice.push({});
    }
    $scope.addonsdata = function(){
        var newItemNo = $scope.Addondata.length+1;
        $scope.Addondata.push({});
    }
```

I know it is because of the same array getting repeated and index may help me.Can anyone suggest help please.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-form. See sample below.

```
 <form name="addForm" novalidate>
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
   <ng-form name="addFieldForm">         
<div class="input-field col s12">
                            <fieldset data-ng-repeat="addondata in Addondata">
                                <div class="input-field col s4">
                                    <input type="text" id="addonname" ng-model="addondata.name" name="addonname" class="form-control" required>
<span ng-show="addFieldForm.addonname.$error.required">required</span>

                                    <label for="name">Name<span class="error_red">*</span></label>

                                    <xt-validation-inline for="addonname"></xt-validation-inline>
                                </div>
                                <div class="input-field col s4">
                                    <input type="text" id="addonprice" ng-model="addondata.price" class="form-control" name="price" required>
<span ng-show="addFieldForm.price.$error.required">required</span>

                                    <label for="price">Price<span class="error_red">*</span></label>

                                    <xt-validation-inline for="addonprice"></xt-validation-inline>
                                </div>
                                <div class="input-field col s4">
                                     <button  type = "button" class="btn addfields" ng-click="addonsdata()" ng-disabled="addFieldForm.$error">ADD</button>
                                    <button  type = "button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="()">Remove</button>
                                </div>
                            </fieldset>   
                        </div>
   </ng-form>
</div>
<input type="submit" ng-disabled="addForm.$invalid" value="Add Add-ons fields"/>
</form>
```